# ASP.NET authentication - multi-app and multi-user database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider

We have a simple ASP.NET app that uses the ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider and all is great.

We want to create a second app on the same server, also use the SqlMembershipProvider, but a different "applicationName" so that the user accounts between the two apps are kept separate.

It looks like this would be possible by making the two different app domains (ie they each have their own web.config), but I'm hoping to just put them in different directories so I don't have 3 web.configs (one for each app, and the main one) that all have to be kept synchronized.  So what I'm after is:

```
/web.config
/APP1 (uses membership provider in /web.config, with userlist A)
/APP2 (uses membership provider in /web.config, with userlist B)
```

It looks simple to define multiple membership providers that use a different 'applicationName' value.

**But how do you tell the system.web.authentication node which membership provider to use?**

As far as I can figure, it will always use the default.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your scenario correctly, it sounds like the only difference between the two applications is the "ApplicationName" property.

So, if you set that in the Application_Start (in Global.asax) of each of the two apps, you should be golden.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Membership.Provider.ApplicationName = "test";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't having multiple Global.asax files (ie one in the APP1 folder and one in the APP2 folder) require separate web.config files? (my assumption is that separate web.config files is actually what defines a separate 'application')

Comment: No, separate web.config files does not make it a separate app.  An application is configured in IIS by going to the properties of a virtual directory and clicking the create button in the application settings section.  Yes, you'd need to use two web.configs.

Comment: Is there any reason why the application_start logic couldn't be a little more complex, just getting the application root and using that to determine a suitable name? Thus two apps with different roots could get different names without multiple web.config files?

Comment: I don't see why not.  As long as they are static and well known.  The users are locked to that ApplicationName, so if the name changes, you'll lose access to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Using your structure I think you'd have to implement your own wrapper around the Membership provider, effectively creating your own provider that just shims the requests and modifies the appname value based on the apps directory.